# How do I enable the user switching feature for the guest account in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, user-accounts

I'm running Windows 8 and have enabled the guest account. When I am logged in as my normal user, and click my user name in the top right corner of the Start screen, I get this menu:

```
Change account picture
Lock
Sign out
Guest
```

If I click Guest, Windows switches to the Guest account.

But my problem is that Guest's user menu just contains:

```
Sign out
```

and not my user name. So to switch back to my user, I need to log out Guest.

**Is there a setting to enable user switching from the Guest account?**

Comment: I am sure it has to do with the extremely low security privileges the guest account has. To defeat this behavior would put the PC at risk, suggest using a regular user account without admin privileges.

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-switch-user-option-in-windows-vista-and-7/). There is some info on enabling and disabling this globally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an alternative procedure that is almost as easy to perform. While you are logged on as guest and want to switch to another user, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>,  then click on Switch user. Enjoy switching from guest account without signing out!

Comment: Works like a charm, how could I miss that? This answer is now the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the low capabilities of the guest account on windows operating systems there is really no way of changing the contents of this menu. Instead of creating a guest account have you considered making a new account all together and setting that account to have very few permissions and no password? This way, you have an account with essentially the same function as a guest account while still being able to switch users to and from your normal account.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan.

Comment: thanks. good luck to you and your future computer related endeavors.